# Unable to drag items from palette in window builder

Tags: java, swing, ide, eclipse-plugin, windowbuilder

I've recently installed window builder plug-in on my Eclipse IDE. When I create a New project and add window builder or anything, I'm unable to drag even a button from the palette.I might be dragging it the wrong way or there might have been something missing in the path etc. Does anyone know the solution to it?  It'll be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by "I'm unable to drag even a button from the palette" - is the palette not responsible to mouse events?

Try creating `File`->`New`->`Other` and selecting `Window Builder`->`Swing Designer`->`Application Window`. Switch to `Design` tab.

Basically you don't drag components/layouts to the graphical view of your window. You should select for example `JButton` by clicking it first. Afterwards you click (second time) on the window.

Comment: I didn't know this thing that we don't drag but we actually click to select an item from the palatte. Thanks so much for that